# nvim not honouring :set background=dark in .vimrc (NVChad)

Tags: background, neovim

I've been a vim user for many years, and this line in my `.vimrc` was always there:
`:set background=dark`

According to neovim's manual, this should be respected by neovim (i.e. it should just read my good ole `~/.vimrc` on startup and not complain). Alas, it's either not reading `.vimrc`, or this instruction is being ignored.
If I start up nvim and manually type `:set background=dark`, it works a treat. Unfortunately, this is rather cumbersome, and without setting it, I can't read most of the text in my editor as it is invisible or too dark to see. My terminals are always black/dark backgrounds (as is pretty standard for most folks, I'd dare say).

What is going wrong?
I'm using neovim v0.10-dev with NVChad

Thanks in advance!
-Al

```
$vim ~/.vimrc
:set background=dark
```